# Serenity: How to differentiate the reports based on the platform used?

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

We are using serenity reports for both platforms to run automation scripts but not sure how to differentiate the features or scenarios in the reports to say which platform is belonged to. I have used tags still no use as those tags are shown for both platforms. Could someone suggest or help me to solve this issue would be a great favour please?

Serenity Version used: 2.0.30

Attached screenshot of a report

[image: Attached screenshot of a report]

Thanks in Advance
Vamc

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a context property or/and tag injection feature. It's nicely described on authors blog here https://johnfergusonsmart.com/running-tests-different-environments-browsers-serenity-bdd/.

Comment: Hi Darsh, Thanks for responding but the link relates to the older version of serenity. My question is related to the latest version of serenity. I have updated the version used too. Ta

Comment: Sorry, but what makes you think it doesn't work in latest version? Did you try that? (and yes, I've tried and both context and tag injection work in latest 2.0.33)

Comment: Darsh, Thanks for quick response.  My scripts are written for both platforms but I do run them individually based on the platform to generate reports accordingly but I can't figure out by the reports that this is based on the platform. I have tried adding tags as `@Android` and `@iOS` individually but both the tags are shown under the tags sections. I want reports should be treated individually based on the platform used.